# Colour a circle above an image

Tags: javascript, react-native

Basically I have an app where I recover data from a pressure. I have in my  an image, and above this image I have put some circle.
What I need to do is to colour this circle when the pressure is major of a value. At the moment I have used a method like:

```
 if (pressure_sx[0] >= 5) 
        { this.setState({ pressColorSx1: '#00438c' }) }
        else { this.setState({ pressColorSx1: '#afeeee' }) }
```

in the render:

```
<View style={{ width: 15, height: 15, borderRadius: 15 / 2, backgroundColor: this.state.pressColorSx1, left: 30, top: 40 }}></View>
```

But this method does not convince me fully, also because after a few seconds it is no longer in real time. In your opinion, how could I do to change color (or basically turn on and off the circle) without working on the color with the setState?

Comment: Create a ImageBackground Inside a View , That will give a much better view Which I have used in many of my projects

Comment: Thank you, and how can I change the colour depending of pressure value?

Comment: Your requirement is to show an image inside a Circular view ?

Comment: nope my requirement is to colour a circle above an image depending of a value xD

Comment: I have yet the circles above an image :)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot in the question , That will  be more specific for developers to answer your question. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203978/discussion-between-ajith-and-jack23).